# Proof of the Specker-Blatter theorem

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory

The [theorem](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.81.728&rep=rep1&type=pdf) in the title states the following: If $\mathcal{C}$ is a class of structures definable in monadic second order logic with unary and binary relation symbols only, then the function $f_\mathcal{C}(n)$ defined as the number of elements in $\mathcal{C}$ over the labeled set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ satisfies a linear recurrence relation modulo $m$ and hence $f_\mathcal{C}(n)$ is ultimately
periodic modulo ${m}$.

My questions concern the proof of the result in "E.~Specker, Application of logic and combinatorics to enumeration problems, in: E. Boerger (Ed.),
Trends in Theoretical Computer Science, Computer Science Press, 1988, pp. 141–169" ([Reprinted](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-0348-9259-9_29) in: "Ernst Specker, Selecta, Birkhaeuser, Basel, 1990, pp. 324–350").

The first two questions concern specific statements in the proof in the above mentioned paper, the third  is of a general nature concerning the proof.

1. In "5." of page the set $\cal{F}_0:=\{v_j\;|\;1\leq j\leq s\}$ for which $|B_i|\leq (p-1)|\cal{B}|$, $(1\leq i\leq r$) is defined. Is it correct that the set $B$ is assumed to be fixed since otherwise $\cal{F}_0$ is not finite?
2. Equation (6.1) on page 51 is
   $$\left(\overrightarrow{B},E.;n\right)=\bigcup_{i=1}^r\left(\overrightarrow{B}^{(i)},E.^{(i)};n-1\right),$$
   with the union being disjoint. Now still on page 51 it is argued that for $v_k\in\mathcal{F}_0\subseteq V\left(\overrightarrow{B},E.;n\right)$ it follows 
   $$v_k=\sum_{i=1}^s w_i(n-1).$$ But according to me it only follows $v_k= w_i(n-1)$ for an $i\in\{1,\ldots,s\}$.
3. In order to count the number of elements in $\mathcal{C}$ over the labeled set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ the number of structures on the larger sets $A\cup\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and $A\cup B\cup\{1,\ldots,n\}$ are counted. Is there a proof that counts the sought-after number directly?